# How to get a list of a particular field from a list of objects in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, member-enumeration

I am new to powershell scripting. Apologies if I am missing something simple.

Let's say I have an object called `object` that has a field called `field`. Now let there be a list of these objects.

How would I get the list of fields in the same order?

In python it would be:

```py
list_of_objects = [o1, o2, o3]
list_of_fields = [i.field for i in list_of_object]
```

Comment: Literally, `$list_of_objects.field`.  In v3 & beyond, powershell implements something called automatic member enumeration which does this for you.  The same works for method calls.  If on v2, you can use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet: `$list_of_objects | % field`.  See: `Get-Help ForEach-Object`

Comment: almost every object in PoSh has a hidden property named `.PSObject` & that has a prop named `.Properties` & each of those has a prop named `.Name`. that seems likely to be what you want. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That is way too low-level for someone brand new to the language.  `.psobject` is a hidden member for a reason :)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - yep, it is hidden ... but it's the most direct way to get the list of props. otherwise you need to use something like `($PSVersionTable | Get-Member -MemberType Properties).Name` to get the names. it think that makes `$PSVersionTable.PSObject.Properties.Name` seem somewhat more appropriate. [*grin*]

Comment: Hey guys, I tried to implement it in the fashion that you mentioned, but it isn't working, and is returning empty. This is the specific example: ```PS C:\Users\ME> $parents.item.registration.parentCompoundNumber
#no return
PS C:\Users\ME> $parents[0].item.registration.parentCompoundNumber
#returns something```

Comment: `parents` are of type `System.array` but when I get down to `item` it no longer is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) is nice, and not so nice, because it unwraps collections for you, and sometimes this can hide that it is masking the elements' members.  When you're using `$parents.item`, you're accessing the array's method, and trying to access *its* members (which there aren't any, so [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) is giving you `$null`):

```
Item           ParameterizedProperty System.Object IList.Item(int index) {get;set;}
```

You can overcome this by using the method I shared in the comments to iterate over each member and avoid this masking:

```
$list = $parents | ForEach-Object -MemberName item
$list.registration.parentCompoundNumber
```

Alternatively, a syntax more people are familiar with:

```
$list = $parents | Select-Object -ExpandProperty item
```

or unrolling it yourself:

```
# you could directly assign the outputs of a `foreach` loop to a variable by
# removing these comments (<##>)
<# $items = #> 
  foreach ($parent in $parents) {
    $parent.item.registration.parentCompoundNumber
  }
```

---

To see when this masking is happening, consider this example which uses the unary array operator:

```
, @('a', 'b', 'c') | Get-Member
```

This will let you observe the wrapping array or collection's members.

Comment: Thank you, the syntax I ended up finding the most readable is ```$ans = $parents | % item | % registration | % parentcompoundNumber```

Comment: @KaiwenChen Glad to help.  A word of caution: using the pipeline (`$obj | cmdlet`) has inherent overhead so over a sufficiently large dataset, it's very slow.

Comment: Yes, I figured this might be the case since it's looping over the list every iteration, but this script only picks up at most 20 results at a time. Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, @TheIncorrigible1; I hope my edit makes sense. As an aside: as far as I know, PowerShell doesn't (yet) support _extension_ methods.

Comment: @mklement0 Unfortunately correct.  You still have to call the extension class on the object, which doesn't really accomplish anything.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Maximilian Burszley's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55424408/45375):

The linked answer contains viable workarounds for the member-name collisions; let me add **a PSv4+ alternative** that is both more concise and faster than a pipeline-based approach:

```
$parent.ForEach('item').registration.parentCompoundNumber
```

Using the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#foreach) with a property name (`'item'`) unambiguously targets the *elements*' members.

---

To offer a slight **reframing of the explanation** for why a workaround is needed:

- PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) essentially treats `$someCollection.someProp` as if you had written `foreach ($element in $someCollection) { $element.someProp }`; that is, the elements of `$someCollection` are enumerated, and the the elements' `.someProp` property values are returned as an array.

  - Note: As in the pipeline, if the collection happens to have just *one* element, that element's property value is returned *as-is*, not as a single-element array.
- However, if *the collection type itself* happens to have a member named `someProp`, *it* is used, and no enumeration takes place; that is, collection-level members *shadow* (take precedence over) element-level members of the same name - and that is what happened with `.Item` in your case.

  - When in doubt, output `$someCollection.someProp` interactively / during debugging to see what it evaluates to.